# Как сделать обработчик контактных форм битрикс24? В чем ошибка?

Tags: php, форма, битрикс24

В чем ошибка? Я хочу сделать обработчик для нескольких контактных форм. Логин и пароль изменил в целях безопасности.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Страница благодарности</title>
<link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>

<?
define('CRM_HOST', 'mysite.bitrix24.ru'); // Домен срм системы
define('CRM_PORT', '443'); 
define('CRM_PATH', '/crm/configs/import/lead.php'); 
define('CRM_LOGIN', 'mywebsite.ru');  // логин
define('CRM_PASSWORD', 'eedasd841df'); // пароль

/********************************************************************************************/

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
  if(isset($_SERVER['POST']['kuh_zvon']))
   {
        'UF_CRM_1547856855' => $_POST['username2'],   // сохраняем имя
        'UF_CRM_1485552555' =>$_POST['phone2'], // сохраняем телефон
   }elseif(isset($_SERVER['POST']['kuh_vopr'])){
    'UF_CRM_1553359931' => $_POST['username3'],   // сохраняем имя
        'UF_CRM_1574155852' =>$_POST['phone3'], // сохраняем телефон
        'UF_CRM_1545224155' =>$_POST['text3'], // сохраняем телефон
   }
};

    // авторизация, проверка логина и пароля
    if (defined('CRM_AUTH'))
    {
        $postData['AUTH'] = CRM_AUTH;
    }
    else
    {
        $postData['LOGIN'] = CRM_LOGIN;
        $postData['PASSWORD'] = CRM_PASSWORD;
    }

    $fp = fsockopen("ssl://".CRM_HOST, CRM_PORT, $errno, $errstr, 30);
    if ($fp)
    {
        // формируем и шифруем строку с данными из формы
        $strPostData = '';
        foreach ($postData as $key => $value)
            $strPostData .= ($strPostData == '' ? '' : '&').$key.'='.urlencode($value);
            $str = "POST ".CRM_PATH." HTTP/1.0\r\n";
            $str .= "Host: ".CRM_HOST."\r\n";
            $str .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
            $str .= "Content-Length: ".strlen($strPostData)."\r\n";
            $str .= "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";

        $str .= $strPostData;

        // отправляем запрос в срм систему
        fwrite($fp, $str );
        $result = '';
        while (!feof($fp))
        {
            $result .= fgets($fp, 128);
        }
        fclose($fp);
        $response = explode("\r\n\r\n", $result);
        $output = '<pre>'.print_r($response[1], 1).'</pre>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Connection Failed! '.$errstr.' ('.$errno.')';
    }
}
//else
// {
//     $output = 'Ошибка';
// }
?>

<!-- То, что будет показываться на странице благодарности -->
<div id="thanks"><h1>Спасибо, Ваша заявка принята.</h1><p class="Pthanks">Наш менеджер свяжется с Вами в течение 15 минут</p>
<p>Если ваша заявка поступила после 17:00, мы обязательно свяжемся с Вами<br/> на следующий день после 9:00.</p><a href="index.html">Вернуться на сайт</a></div>';
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Так а какую ошибку получаете в итоге?

Comment: Здравствуйте, Кириллю Выдает ошибку HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: `'UF_CRM_1547856855' => $_POST['username2'],` и прочие такие же строки, что они значат?  Может, Вы хотели засунуть это в ассоциативный массив?  А то получается, Вы присваиваете строкам какие-то значения.

Comment: это id пользовательского поля и присвоение ему имени

Comment: я делал на основании этой статьи и все работает только для одной формы

Comment: https://smartlanding.biz/kak-dobavit-svoi-polya-dlya-formirovaniya-lidov-v-crm-bitrix24.html

Comment: Посмотрите внимательно в первом коде php приведённом в статье по Вашей же ссылке на строки 14-20, там создаётся переменная типа `array`, в ней ключам этого ассоциативного массива присваивается значение из `$_POST`.  А у Вас просто строки, без создания переменной.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    if(isset($_SERVER['POST']['kuh_zvon']))
    {
        $postData = array(
            'TITLE' => $_POST['kuh_zvon'],
            'UF_CRM_1547856855' => $_POST['username2'],   // сохраняем имя
            'UF_CRM_1485552555' => $_POST['phone2'], // сохраняем телефон
        );
    }
    elseif(isset($_SERVER['POST']['kuh_vopr']))
    {
        $postData = array(
            'TITLE' => $_POST['kuh_vopr'],
            'UF_CRM_1553359931' => $_POST['username3'],   // сохраняем имя
            'UF_CRM_1574155852' => $_POST['phone3'], // сохраняем телефон
            'UF_CRM_1545224155' => $_POST['text3'], // сохраняем телефон
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: не работает, но работает вот в таком виде только для одной формы <code>if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    // получаем данные из полей и задаем название лида
    
    $postData = array(
        'TITLE' => $_POST['kuh_zvon'], // сохраняем нашу метку и формируем заголовок лида
        'UF_CRM_1553359931' => $_POST['username2'],   // сохраняем имя
        'UF_CRM_1553455522' =>$_POST['phone2'], // сохраняем телефон
        
    );

    
 </code>

Comment: Обновил ответ, так тоже не работает?

Comment: не работает ((((

Comment: Ещё уберите строку `};`, эта скобка явно лишняя, может она ошибку даёт.

Comment: если убрать то синтаксическая ошибка появляется

Comment: и также не работает.... я уже голову сломал

Comment: так по крайней мере скрипт срабатывает и выжает сообщение что заявка принята но не выдается сообщение в crm о заявке

Comment: $postData = array(
'TITLE' => $_POST['kuh_zvon'], // сохраняем нашу метку и формируем заголовок лида
'UF_CRM_1553359931' => $_POST['username2'], // сохраняем имя
'UF_CRM_1553455522' =>$_POST['phone2'], // сохраняем телефон

);

Comment: если скопировать этот код дважды в таком виде только поля добавить и поменять UF_CRM

Comment: пожалуйста заново перечитайте новый текст я там убрал опечатки